# Visual Studio Code debugging with Debug Console REPL and Watch pane

Tags: visual-studio-code

When Debugging .NET (C# or F#) in Visual Studio Code, is there a reference documentation about what is the syntax to be used in the Watch pane or the debug console REPL?

For example, I can see an array element with myArray[4], but how do I display an array slice like myArray[3..6]?

[image]

Comment: what is the C# expression to get  a slice

Comment: @rioV8 
var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var slice1 = array[2..]; // From index 2 to the end
var slice2 = array[..2]; // From the start to index 1
var slice3 = array[1..3]; // From the index 1 to index 2
var slice4 = array[..]; // The whole array
var slice5 = array[3..1]; // Throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: if that are valid C# expressions you can create a feature/bug request at the C# VSC extension repo